# How do I check that the private file system is setup correctly from hook_requirements()?

Tags: 8, hooks, files

I'm working on a module that will need to place files in the private file directory.  I'd like to check that the private file system is working from within `hook_requirements()` so I can provide both an install requirement and a status check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few different ways.

Use the \Drupal\Core\Site\Settings class static method `get`:

```
if (\Drupal\Core\Site\Settings::get('file_private_path')) {

}
```

Check for the existence of the `stream_wrapper.private` service, which is only instantiated when the above check passes. Need to catch the appropriate exception coming from Symfony. **Update 2017.01.23** @Berdir suggests using the getContainer method, which means we don't have to catch the exception!

```
if (\Drupal::hasService('stream_wrapper.private')) {

}
```

Use the `file_system` service to check if it's a valid scheme. This will basically check if the above service's class exists.

```
$fileSystem = \Drupal::service('file_system');

// Check if the private file stream wrapper is ready to use.
if ($fileSystem->validScheme('private')) {

}
```